# Fatal error: Access denied for user 'deltatours'@'10.30.72.4' (using password: YES)'

Tags: php, xcode

I apologize for posting this kind of question again. However, I cannot relate my problem with others. I have never learned coding in my whole life; however, my job requests me to fix this for them. The problem comes from the line 59 **"$this-conn = new PDO (....)** this part.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'deltatours'@'10.30.72.4' (using password: YES)' in
>   /data/27/1/88/149/1414964/user/1519375/htdocs/core/class/db.class.php:59
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /data/27/1/88/149/1414964/user/1519375/htdocs/core/class/db.class.php(59):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=205....', 'deltatours', 'Delta12345') #1
>   [internal function]: db->__construct() #2
>   /data/27/1/88/149/1414964/user/1519375/htdocs/core/framework.php(88):
>   ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array) #3
>   /data/27/1/88/149/1414964/user/1519375/htdocs/core/class/language.class.php(60):
>   framework::lib('db') #4
>   /data/27/1/88/149/1414964/user/1519375/htdocs/core/class/language.class.php(29):
>   language->set('') #5 [internal function]: language->__construct() #6
>   /data/27/1/88/149/1414964/user/1519375/htdocs/core/framework.php(88):
>   ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array) #7
>   /data/27/1/88/149/1414964/user/1519375/htdocs/core/framework.php(284):
>   framework::lib('language') #8 /data/27/1/88/149/14 in
>   /data/27/1/88/149/1414964/user/1519375/htdocs/core/class/db.class.php
>   on line 59

Please kindly guide me!

```
    public function __construct($pageName = 'page') {
    $_config = parent::lib('config', 'db');
    $this->_prefix = $_config->get('prefix');
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $_config->get('host') . ';dbname=' . $_config-    
    >get('name');
    $this->_conn = new PDO($dsn, $_config->get('user'), $_config-
    >get('password'));
    $this->_conn->query("SET NAMES '" . $_config->get('char') . "'");   
    self::setPageName($pageName);
```

Comment: Your username/password/host credentials are incorrect, or that user does not have access to the database.

Comment: It could be the correct username/password, but wrong host.  Mysql grants access to a user identified by a password, @ a specific host (or a wildcard for all hosts).  If the ip or server changed, it could suddenly cause this problem.

Comment: What I want to know is do I need to change anything on the coding above. What can I do now to fix this? Change a username/password/host?

Comment: Talk to your database administrator or host and get the proper username, password, host, and database name. If you have access to the database, you can try `SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user` and make sure that `'deltatours'@'10.30.72.4'` exists. `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'deltatours'@'10.30.72.4'` will tell you if that user has access to the database you need.

Comment: I do have the access to username, password, host and database name. 
Could you kindly tell me how to test the method you just mentioned?
I really need detailed instruction. I do not know anything about coding. I can use dreamweaver to change the coding, but I have to know how to do it. Please!
 ( SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user and make sure that 'deltatours'@'10.30.72.4' exists. SHOW GRANTS FOR 'deltatours'@'10.30.72.4')

Comment: Those need to be done within the mysql console/commandline or PHPMyAdmin. If you don't have access to that, check with your host or database administrator.